# Correct way to pass inputs into event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

I have created a onClick event handler in my code and came across a slightly confusing occurrence. I was testing a `console.log` to see what was being passed into the event handler, and found that although a variable called `teamId` was being passed, the `console.log` suggested a class was passed into it.

My original code was as follow:

```
    
    const renderedOptions = Object.keys(comps,).map((compName, index) =>{

        const teamId = comps[compName].id

        return(
            <div 
                key={teamId}
                className="item"
                onClick = {(teamId)=>console.log(teamId)}
            >
                {compName}
            </div>
        )
    })
```

The `console.log` returned `Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: div.item, …}`.

I then adjusted the code by changing the `onClick` arrow function to be
 `()=>console.log(teamId)` which returned the value of the constant `teamId` as I initially expected.

Can someone explain why `(teamId)=>console.log(teamId)` returns a class object, whilst `()=>console.log(teamId)` returns the actual value of teamId?

Comment: First argument of an event handler callback is the event object. Suggest you review in more detail the Forms section of React docs where this is all explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because event handlers are called with the event object as argument. It would be more logical to have code like `(event) => {...}`.

But of course you can choose the name of your argument yourself. So in your example `(teamId) => {...}` you are calling the argument `teamId` (shadowing the local variable in the outer scope which had the same name), yet of course you still get the event object passed into it, and when you write `teamId` inside the function body you actually access the event object that you get in the argument (because it's the "closest" (scope-wise) variable with that name).

With `() => {...}` (or `(anyOtherName) => {...}`) you don't clash with the outer scope's `teamId` variable name and hence writing `teamId` inside your function accesses that variable instead.